# Is Stack Exchange Meta data available on Data Explorer?

Tags: support, data-explorer, meta

I am trying to run a query in Data Explorer and can't seem to target Meta SE. I've tried a few different ways (Stack Exchange Meta, Meta, Big meta, Meta Stack Exchange), pasted the URL meta.stackexchange.com (with and without http, https) and can't seem to access it (I get sent to 3D Printing Meta).

Is the data for Meta SE not available on Data Explorer or am I missing something?

ETA: Donald Duck's answer below fixes my problem but shows me that something seems amiss. Typing Meta Stack Exchange and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> when using the button next to "Compose Query" currently sends to Software Recommendations Meta.

[image]

Typing Meta Stack Exchange in that field without pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> doesn't toggle the same list as the Switch sites option (it doesn't do anything if I don't press Enter)

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's available, it's just under all the per-site Metas. You can find it if you type "Meta Stack Exchange" without pressing Enter and then scroll down a bit in the list of suggestions:

[image]

I agree though that it would be better if searching for "Meta Stack Exchange" would give Meta Stack Exchange as the first result, but unfortunately that's not the way it is. I hope they will fix that.

Comment: :-O... I've been using the feature next to the "Compose query" button and typing Meta Stack Exchange sends me to Software Recommendations Meta...

Comment: @Emilie You can do exactly the same thing with the "Compose query" button. Again, pressing Enter will take you to the first suggestion, so you don't want to do that.

Comment: I don't actually have a choice to press Enter there... No list appears there (but it works when I use the same place you feature in your answer)

Comment: As of yesterday, it should no longer be the case: the name "Stack Exchange" has been [omitted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332160/long-site-title-messes-up-sede-site-list-formatting) from every site name except Meta Stack Exchange.