# Long site title messes up SEDE site list formatting

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, data-explorer

On the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer homepage](https://data.stackexchange.com/), if you scroll down a bit, you'll encounter a site with a very long title: [Software Recommendations Meta Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/). A title this long messes up the formatting of the list (at least in the latest Firefox and Safari on macOS Mojave):

[image]